# What does -rss mean at the end of this command

Tags: linux

I am wondering what does the -rss means at the end of the following:

ps aux –sort -rss

I have tried to use google to figure it out but no search has really helped me with it and I am trying to use the man pages in linux and still no luck. I hope that someone here can explain what it means to me.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It is **R**esident **S**et **S**ize - how much "actual memory" is your program using (more or less).

From [man ps:](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html)

> resident set size, the non-swapped physical memory that a task has
>   used (in kilobytes). (alias rssize, rsz).